# Delphi 10.1 sem SQLConnection, ADOConnection, IBDatabase

Tags: delphi

I'm new to Delphi, and I'm trying to find an componnent to connect with a SQL Server database. In Delphi XE I used ADOConnection, but I can't find any component that serves to this propose.

Comment: Delphi 10.1 Berlin still has TADOConnection and the other ADO related components - they're in the same place (DBGo on the component palette) as they were in XE. IBDatabase is only for connecting to InterBase.  What is your question?

Comment: As you can see on this picture: https://postimg.org/image/rnfn2jokd/ I can't find those components... Any of them!

Comment: What version of Berlin do you have? (Professional, Enterprise, Architect) I'm looking at the DBGo tab in my component palette right now, in a new blank VCL forms application, and they're all there. Ah, wait - you're trying to access SQL Server from a FMX application. Is it a Win32 or Win64 application? If not, ADO is not available; it's a Windows only API. Please [edit] your question to be more specific about the type of project you're trying to create. We can't help you if you fail to give us the relative details.

Comment: In About option it says: 
Embarcadero® Delphi 10.1 Berlin Version 24.0.22858.6822 
and below:
Product License Status: Registered, Starter, 
I downloaded the free version on the site

Comment: And right below License Status it tells you which Edition you have, which is what I asked you.

Comment: There's your problem. Starter does not include DB components. You'll need a higher edition (Professional at least).

Comment: Oh Ok so, thank you a lot!

Comment: For a list of features available in each edition, see https://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/product-editions

Comment: You can use Zeos Lib on starter https://sourceforge.net/projects/zeoslib/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the Starter Edition, which does not include database access components according to the [Delphi Product Editions matrix](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/product-editions). In order to connect to databases, you'll need to upgrade to a higher SKU (edition).

Most third-party alternatives won't work with Standard either, because the underlying classes they would need to use don't exist in the Standard SKU.